# Distribution of monotouch application for iphone only

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, distribution

I'm trying to get a ios monotouch project distributed for iphone only. But whenever i have uploaded to itunes connect the binary details keep telling me it is also available for ipad.

I did specify the targetdevice in the info.plist
Anyone had the same problem with monotouch?? or better, knows how to solve this!

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't target iPhone only. The iPad is 100% iPhone-compatible, and will run all iPhone apps (and there is nothing you can do about it).

Maybe you can explain why you want to restrict your app to iPhone only?

Comment: Whatsapp seems to target iPhone only - it would be interesting to see how they did that.

Comment: I wonder if setting the telephony key in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities would achieve this? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3

Comment: The ipad application had to differ from the iphone. So the first version was dedicated for the iphone only. It's all about giving the customer what he wants, so my hands where tied. But it is possible to set this in the info.plist. This was a monotouch compatability problem